# Aproveitar API Android em aplicações Desktop

Tags: java, android, api, sdk

Posso aproveitar os códigos de uma API feita para Android e usar numa aplicação java desktop ?
PS.: Não manjo nada de Java, estou disposto a aprender. Sei apenas Delphi e C++...
No delphi por exemplo, posso aproveitar o código mobile e utilizar no desktop e vice versa.

Comment: a API foi feita por você? Ela é genérica ou utiliza recursos do SDK de android? Se sua API não utiliza nenhum recurso do SDK **é possível** que ela possa ser aproveitada em ambas plataformas

Comment: Corrigindo as definições: uma biblioteca fornece uma API (_Application Programming Interface_), isto é, um conjunto de classes, interfaces e métodos públicos que você pode usar para desenvolver um aplicativo. Um SDK pode incluir uma biblioteca, entre outras ferramentas (_debuggers_, ambiente de desenvolvimento ou IDE), e você ainda pode usar no seu código bibliotecas que não pertencem ao SDK (essas bibliotecas externas podem servir para vários ambientes, incluindo mobile e desktop). O aplicativo que você desenvolve usando SDK e bibliotecas se chama aplicativo final mesmo.

Comment: Entendi @Piovezan, só me tire essa dúvida... vou tentar ser um pouco mais objetivo. A sony tem API de suas câmeras em android, poderia utilizar essa API em alguma aplicação desktop?

Comment: No meu entendimento, a API de câmeras em Android da Sony é específica para Android (isso se não for específica para plataformas da Sony, isto é, combinações de hardware e versão de Android da Sony). Ela espera que o sistema operacional forneça recursos como intents, etc. específicos do Android, que a plataforma desktop não pode fornecer. Fosse porém um Android para PC (arquitetura x86), daí poderia funcionar.

Comment: @Piovezan obrigado pelo comentário, agregou bastante

Comment: @WilliamBarreto Se a resposta foi útil siga [essas orientações](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Sugiro também aguardar por comentários de outros usuários que possam agregar mais à resposta, inclusive fornecendo alternativas para seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

No meu entendimento, a API de câmeras em Android da Sony é específica para Android (isso se não for específica para plataformas da Sony, isto é, combinações de hardware e versão de Android da Sony). Ela espera que o sistema operacional forneça recursos como intents, etc. específicos do Android, que a plataforma desktop não pode fornecer. Fosse porém um Android para PC (arquitetura x86), daí poderia funcionar, mas aí estamos falando em não rodar Windows nem Linux.